# Pdfbox-Android shows empty page

Tags: android-studio, pdfbox

I recently used pdfbox android library because iText is under AGPL. I tried running following code.

```
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
PDPage page= new PDPage();
document.addPage(page);
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagesObject.get(0).image); //imagesobject is string path
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(imagesObject.get(0).image,document);
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page,true,true);
contentStream.drawImage(pdImage,70,70,pdImage.getWidth(), pdImage.getHeight());
contentStream.close();
document.save(file);
document.close();
```

PDF is saved with empty page no image is shown. I noticed size of pdf is 6mb, Which means the image has been drawn but can't see. Any Fix?

Also I am using ported library by TomRoush.

This is the link for pdf that was generated [here](https://gofile.io/d/G1hQPa)

[image]

Comment: please upload the PDF somewhere

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I have been testing this past few hours, it works on few androids properly, later I changed the `PDImageXObject.createFromFile(image,document)` to `LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, bitmap);` , now it works. Anyways I have added link to pdf also in question.

Comment: I looked at the PDF and the image is a PNG is embedded 1:1. Could it be that this was indeed a PNG file but had a JPEG extension? I looked at the source https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/tom_roush/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/image/PDImageXObject.java it uses the extension to decide.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr how can it be PNG file have and JPEG extension. That would mean image is corrupted and can't be viewed. But image is correct and has PNG extension.

Comment: Must be FileTypeDetector is not working properly [link](https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android/blob/b0ffa73ef98810b0088b40ed39c1a7c3bb1c0b0a/library/src/main/java/com/tom_roush/pdfbox/util/filetypedetector/FileTypeDetector.java#L35)

Comment: What is the name of the file on your system? The file inside the PDF is a PNG file and has the correct magic number for PNG.

Comment: oh yes your were right. Image has `.jpg` at the end `Image_1622096658030.jpg` . I dont know how I missed that, I was sure that it was png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the image had a .jpg extension in the name, but was a PNG image file. The `PDImageXObject createFromFile(String imagePath, PDDocument doc)` method assumes the file type by its extension, so it embedded the file 1:1 in the PDF and assigned a DCT filter. Both of these would have been correct for a jpeg file, but not for png.

So the solution would be to either rename the file, or use the `createFromFileByContent` method.